# Counting a String's Lowercase Letters

Tags: java, string, lowercase

I was looking around forums and found a helpful code on how to count lowercase letters in an inputted string. Thing is, after testing it, I saw it only counts lowercase letters within the first word typed. So, for example, if I type: **HeRE** the counter will say I've typed in 1 lowercase letter (which is correct), but if I type in: **HeRE i am** the counter will still only say 1 instead of 4. It's only counting the lowercase letters in the first word. How do I get it to count lowercase letters in my entire string?

Code thus far:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 public class countingLowerCaseStrings {
 public static void main(String args[]){
 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

 System.out.println("Enter your string: ");
 String input = scanner.next();

 int LowerCaseLetterCounter = 0;
   for (char ch : input.toCharArray()) {
     if (Character.isLowerCase(ch)) {
     LowerCaseLetterCounter++;
  }
}

   System.out.println ("Number of lower case letters in this string is: " +
   LowerCaseLetterCounter);

   }

  }
```

Thanks a bunch for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scanner.next();` reads the **first available word**, not the entire line.

So if you input "HeRE i am" it will just read "HeRE".

Change it to `scanner.nextLine()`:

```
System.out.println("Enter your string: ");
String input = scanner.nextLine();
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/si4Yhc) - look at `stdin` and `stdout` panels.

Comment: I totally missed that! Thanks dude, easy fix and I can't believe I didn't notice it! You're awesome! ;)

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of interest, Java 8 provides a fairly streamlined way of achieving the same thing:

```
scanner.nextLine().chars().filter(Character::isLowerCase).count()
```